# ClassNotFoundException in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Hi I am totally new to JMeter. I am trying to record a UI (web) Test and is using BlazeMeter. I have recorded a test and opened it in JMeter (jmx file), then had added listeners. But when I run I cannot find any resukts and its showing 
ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.HTMLParseError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser

I am not able to find what is to be done. Please help.

Comment: I have Java 17 on my Windows 10 machine, & JMeter version 5.5. I'm facing a similar error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.URLCollection.addURL(URLCollection.java:82) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is your JMeter version? My expectation is that you are using something very outdated, make sure you always use the latest version of JMeter, moreover it is recommended as one of [JMeter Best Practices](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html)

You can grab one at [JMeter Downloads](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page at any time

---

There might also be the case that BlazeMeter can be not in sync (i.e. 1 version behind the JMeter release) so I would recommend contacting [BlazeMeter Support](https://www.blazemeter.com/support) if the situation won't be solved by upgrading your JMeter version to the latest one.

Comment: I have Java 17 on my Windows 10 machine, & JMeter version 5.5, but I'm getting this error: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.URLCollection.addURL(URLCollection.java:82) ~[ApacheJMeter_http.jar:5.5]`
The BlazeMeter version I used was v 5.4.0